# Delete Multiple Specified Folders (+Contents) in Python

Tags: python, delete-file, directory, shutil

i'm trying to learn Phython so I dont know a lot of this coding language yet ;)

I'm trying to delete some pre-specified folders (including it's content) with a python script, I know how to remove ONE folder like this:

```
def purgeOld():
    import os,xbmc,shutil
    xvbmc = os.listdir(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/')))
    addonfolder = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/'))
    for item in xvbmc:
        if ('plugin.video.Blaaat0') in item:
            print str(xvbmc)+str(item)
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(addonfolder+item, ignore_errors=True)
            except:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    return
```

Now I'm trying to do this with multiple folders this I what I've got and is allmost working, I does remove the content of my specified folders but not the folder itself, how can I change this OR should I do thie completly different? 
*I copy/pasted a few google results from here and turned it into this 'Frankencode'* **;-p**

```
class cacheEntry:
    def __init__(self, namei, pathi):
        self.name = namei
        self.path = pathi

def setupXvbmcEntries():
    entries = 3 #make sure this refelcts the amount of entries you have
    dialogName = ["Blaaat1", "Blaaat2", "Blaaat3"]
    pathName = ["special://home/addons/repository.Blaaat1","special://home/addons/repository.Blaaat2",
                "special://home/addons/repository.Blaaat3"]

    XvbmcEntries = []

    for x in range(entries):
        XvbmcEntries.append(cacheEntry(dialogName[x],pathName[x]))

    return XvbmcEntries

def purgeOld():
    import os,xbmc,shutil
#    xvbmc = os.listdir(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/')))
#    addonfolder = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/'))
#    for item in xvbmc:
#        if ('plugin.video.Blaaat0') in item:
#            print str(xvbmc)+str(item)
#            try:
#                shutil.rmtree(addonfolder+item, ignore_errors=True)
#            except:
#                pass
#        else:
#            pass

    XvbmcEntries = setupXvbmcEntries()

    for entry in XvbmcEntries:
        xvbmcaddons = xbmc.translatePath(entry.path)
        if os.path.exists(xvbmcaddons)==True:    
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(xvbmcaddons):
                file_count = 0
                file_count += len(files)
                if file_count > 0:

                        for f in files:
                            os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
                        for d in dirs:
                            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))

                else:
                    pass

    return
```

Hopefully I'm pretty close? OR should I do it in some cleaner/better way perhaps? With kind regards, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

1st try/test, changed it into:

```
def purgeOld():

    XvbmcEntries = setupXvbmcEntries()

    for entry in XvbmcEntries:
        xvbmcaddons = xbmc.translatePath(entry.path)
        if os.path.exists(xvbmcaddons)==True:    
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(xvbmcaddons):
                file_count = 0
                file_count += len(files)
                if file_count > 0:

                    for f in files:
                        try:
                            os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
                        except:
                            pass
                    for d in dirs:
                        try:
                            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d), ignore_errors=True)
                        except:
                            pass

                    try:
                        shutil.rmtree(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/repository.Blaaat1')), ignore_errors=True)
                        shutil.rmtree(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/repository.Blaaat2')), ignore_errors=True)
                        shutil.rmtree(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/repository.Blaaat3')), ignore_errors=True)
                        dialog.ok("TEST-PURGE", 'we found some orphaned dependencies...','', 'NOTE: a REBOOT is highly recommended!')
                        xbmc.executebuiltin("UpdateLocalAddons")
                    except:             
                        pass

            else:
                #dialog.ok("Purge test dialog2", "Crap cleaner all done...")
                pass
        else:
            #dialog.ok("Purge test dialog3", "Crap cleaner all done...")
            pass

    dialog.ok("Purge dialog DONE!", "everything is as clean as a whistle...")
#   return
```

This does remove all the folders, but now I have to specify 'what to remove' twice, this does seem a little redundant? 
(entries are specified in setupXvbmcEntries earlier, now again/extra under try: etc), I assume this can be done prettier, invoke 'xvbmcaddons' again somehowe perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

2nd try/test, 
and still in need of double removal (1st run leaves empty directories somehow)...

```
def purgeOLD():

    XvbmcEntries = setupXvbmcEntries()

    for entry in XvbmcEntries:
        xvbmcaddons = xbmc.translatePath(entry.path)
        if os.path.exists(xvbmcaddons)==True:    
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(xvbmcaddons):
                file_count = 0
                file_count += len(files)
                if file_count > 0:

                    for f in files:
                        try:
                            os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
                        except OSError:
                            os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
                    for d in dirs:
                        try:
                            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d), ignore_errors=True)
                        except:
                            pass

                else:
                    shutil.rmtree(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/','plugin.video.Blaaat1')), ignore_errors=True)
                    shutil.rmtree(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/','repository.Blaaaaat2')), ignore_errors=True)
                    shutil.rmtree(xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://home/addons/','repository.Blaaaaat3')), ignore_errors=True)
                    dialog.ok("TEST-PURGE", 'we found some orphaned dependencies...','', 'NOTE: a REBOOT is highly recommended!')
                    xbmc.executebuiltin("UpdateLocalAddons")
                    pass

        else:
          # dialog.ok("Purge test dialog", "Crap cleaner all done...")
            pass

    dialog.ok("-= ALL DONE =- ", 'your system seems in good condition','', '(everything is as clean as a whistle)')
```